ReasonsGridView_CellFormatting messes up the datagridview display
I looked at this post:
How can I change the background color of a row from my datagridview if column 1 holds a string with "Aborted"?
to implement the change I want.  But there's a processing thing going on that's messing up my datagridview display.  There are 350+ rows in my DataGridView, for the record, with 18 of them visible at a time.
I'm storing the color I want the row to be in a DataGridViewCell, colindex 25.
Here is my code:
private void ReasonsGridView_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.ColumnIndex == 25 && e.Value != null)
    {
        var style = ReasonsGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = (Color)e.Value;
    }
}

And this is the kind of thing that gets rendered after scrolling around in the grid view for a while.

And here it is with RowPostPaint (please suggest alternatives to the way I'm doing this).  But it results in the same behavior.
private void ReasonsGridView_RowPostPaint(object sender, DataGridViewRowPostPaintEventArgs e)
{
    DataGridView dataGridView = sender as DataGridView;
    DataGridViewRow row = dataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex];
    DataGridViewCell cell = row.Cells["BackColor"];

    if (!row.IsNewRow)
    {
        row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = (Color)cell.Value;
    }

}



No, don't implement the RowPostPaint event to set style properties. Do if you need to adjust the appearance of the row after its cells are painted. Handle the CellFormatting instead to set style properties when some condition is met and set e.FormattingApplied = true;.

Try to move that code to the RowPrePaint event handler (defines states before the Row is painted). You can also refactor in var color = (Color)dataGridView["BackColor", e.RowIndex].Value; if (dataGridView.NewRowIndex != e.RowIndex && row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor != color) { row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = color; } -- Also, try to double-buffer the DataGridView, as shown here (code in the Constructor of the Form)

@dr.null Since the OP is trying to change the background color of the entire Row, RowPrePaint is OK; RowPostPaint not so much. Not clear whether the color can change multiple times, but the CellFormatting event is called a gazillion times, the Rows' painting proc only when scrolling

@Jimi Agreed...

Many thanks for the feedback, gang.  The Double Buffering appears to have resolved the issue with the overlapping text (as well as the RowPrePaint event instead of RowPostPaint, of course).  Now, though, even when I set the defaultcellstyle in the constructor to Transparent or White, the backcolor is always black, until you click on a cell, then the BackColor only for that cell turns blue, then back to black when you click out.  The rows which are NOT transparent are working ok.  Something silly?
